# Iot Node-red AutoStart

Tags: iot, node-red

I have a Siemens IoT where I installed Node-RED. I'm following a project that is based on receiving data and save them in a db via Node-RED and must be active 24h every day.

I wanted to know if there was an auto-run in case the IoT went off to start everything automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might be helpful,I am using this in my RPI.

`sudo systemctl enable nodered.service`

https://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi

If pm2 is possible to install, then you can try this too.

`sudo npm install -g pm2
pm2 start /usr/bin/node-red -- -v`

https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/running

Comment: thanks i solved , there is a option in iot2000setup for start automatically node-red